# When copying or moving std::function, can I update a lambda-captured this pointer?

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a class which holds a `std::function` as a member variable. The `std::function` returns a value which is usually determined from the lambda-captured 'this' pointer from a containing class. When I swap two items of the containing class, the `std::functions` are swapped, but their lambda-captured pointers aren't swapped, so the functions are now misaligned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


class FunctionHolder
{
public:
    using F = std::function<int()>;

    FunctionHolder(const F& f) : func(f) {}

    FunctionHolder(FunctionHolder&& other) noexcept :
        func(std::move(other.func))
    {}

    FunctionHolder& operator= (FunctionHolder&& other) noexcept
    {
        if (&other != this)
            func = std::move(other.func);

        return *this;
    }
    
    F func;
};

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(const int i) :
        value(i),
        f([this]() { return value; })
    {}

    int getValue() const { return value; }

    void run() const { std::cout << getValue() << " : " << std::invoke(f.func) << '\n'; }
    
private:
    FunctionHolder f;
    int value;
};




int main()
{
    auto t1 = TestClass(1), t2 = TestClass(2);

    std::cout << "before swap" << '\n';
    t1.run();
    t2.run();

    std::swap(t1, t2);

    std::cout << '\n' << "after swap" << '\n';
    t1.run();
    t2.run();
}
```

This outputs:

```
before swap
1 : 1
2 : 2

after swap
2 : 1
1 : 2
```

It makes sense why this would happen, since the `std::function` doesn't really know what is captured. I'm wondering if there is anything I can do about it? Is there a way to somehow update the pointers as well, or is there an alternative strategy I should consider?

Comment: You can't touch those captured pointers without some horrendous hacks. Don't capture `this`, pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Implement proper copy/assignment operators that does what you want. Note that your `FunctionHolder` move constructor/assignment could simply be defaulted here, no need to implement them.

Comment: Yeah I put those constructors there so that I could chance whether the std::function was moved or copied, but you're right that it's unnecessary.

Comment: I'm wondering if there could be a solution using std::bind?

Comment: What you want is to access the class object from one of its member, this is not possible in C++. What you need to do is overload proper constructors/operators to maintain consistency between `f` and the containing object. `std::bind` is no different from a lambda so it would not change anything.

Comment: change the swap of the containing class to swap everything, but the `std::functions` or to swap them specifically one more time.